# Alternating upcase/downcase for a string in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a function that will return a string formatted with alternative upcase/downcase in Common Lisp. For example, entering "stackoverflow" should return the string "StAcKoVeRfLoW". Here's my attempt, but it just returns a list of cons pairs. Am I on the right track?

```cl
(defun mockify (chars)
  (let ((lst (coerce chars 'list)))
    (if (equal lst nil) nil
        (coerce (cons
                 (cons (char-upcase (car lst)) (char-downcase (cadr lst)))
                      (mockify (cddr lst)))
                'string))))

CL-USER> (mockify "meow")
((#\M . #\e) (#\O . #\w))
```

Comment: doesn't the code result in an error?

Comment: I think so if the length of the input is odd instead of even.

Comment: Update: yes, the code in question results in an error. I had fiddled around by setting the return from `'string` to `'sequence`, which does not result in error, and forgot to include it in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun mockify (chars)
  (let ((lst (coerce chars 'list)))
    (if (equal lst nil)
        ;; return nil
        nil
        ;; return a string (coerce)
        (coerce 
          ;; a list whose elements are cons-cells, but ...
          (cons (cons (char-upcase (car lst))
                      (char-downcase (cadr lst)))
                ;; ... the rest is computed by calling mockify,
                ;; which returns either an empty list or a string
                (mockify (cddr lst)))
          'string))))
```

The types of your expressions are confusing, and in fact your example leads to an error when using SBCL:

```
> (mockify "meow")
The value
  (#\O . #\w)
is not of type
  CHARACTER
when setting an element of (ARRAY CHARACTER)
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

Also, you are going to have to handle corner cases in your code, because as is, it is possible that `(cadr list)`, i.e. `(second list)`, is called on a  list that has only one element. Then, the result would be `NIL` and `char-downcase` would fail with an error.

### Using only strings

I'd suggest writing a version of the function that does not use intermediate lists:

1. let R be the `string-downcase` of the whole string
2. then modify every other character of R by upcasing it

So for example, one way to do it (among others) would be:

```
(defun mockify (chars)
  (let ((chars (string-downcase chars)))
    (prog1 chars
      (upcasify chars 0))))

(defun upcasify (string index)
  (when (< index (length string))
    (setf (char string index) (char-upcase (char string index)))
    (upcasify string (+ index 2))))
```

### Using only lists

If you prefer having a recursive function that processes lists, I'd rather define it in layers:

1. coerce string to list
2. process the list recursively
3. eventually, coerce the resulting list back to a string

This will avoid doing conversions from strings to lists at every step, and make the code simpler at each level.

```
(defun mockify (chars)
  (coerce (mockify-list (coerce chars 'list)) 'string))

(defun mockify-list (chars)
  ...)
```

The list version is recursive and look like what you tried to do, but take care of corner cases.

Comment: Thank you for helping me think about this differently. This is just what I needed -- downcasing entire string first, then upcasing every other char.

Answer (score 5):

Using `MAP`: we are creating a new string, moving over the original string and upcase/downcase based on an alternating boolean variable.

```
CL-USER 353 > (let ((string "stackoverflow")
                    (upcase t))
                (map (type-of string)
                     (lambda (element)
                       (prog1 (if upcase
                                  (char-upcase element)
                                (char-downcase element))
                         (setf upcase (not upcase))))
                     string))
"StAcKoVeRfLoW"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is more than one way to do it.  Here is a `loop` based solution:

```
(let ((string "StackOverflow"))
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (loop :for c :across string
          :for up := t :then (not up)
          :do (princ (if up
                         (char-upcase c)
                         (char-downcase c))
                     s))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Fun thing - I actually wrote a similar thing some time ago.

https://github.com/phoe/string-pokemonize